# TikZ figure does not appear to be centered with respect to caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm new to Ti*k*Z and I'm having problems in centering a Ti*k*Z picture
with respect to its caption (and the page margins as well).
By activating the picture's `background rectangle`, it seems
that extra white space is added both to the top and to the
right of the picture (the rectangle is centered but the
picture is not).

The same problem does not occur with other Ti*k*Z pictures in the
same document.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % Activate to show the page margins

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, backgrounds, shapes, arrows, shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
  \centering
% \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{Figure03.png}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  [show background rectangle]
    % Fading settings
    \tikzfading[name         = fade out
               , inner color = transparent!100
               , outer color = transparent!10 ]
    % Axes
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (0,0) -- (-0.6,-0.6) node[anchor=north west]{$X$};
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (0,0) -- (1.2,0)     node[anchor=north]{$Y$};
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (0,0) -- (0,1.2)     node[anchor=east]{$Z$};
    % Ellipse filling
    \fill [ color        = cyan
          , opacity      = 0.25
          , path fading  = fade out
          , fading angle = -30
          , rotate       = -30]
          (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 3.0cm);
    % Ellipse
    \draw [ name path  = ellipse 1
          , rotate     = -30]
          (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 3.0cm);
    % Oblique axis
    \draw [ name path = oblique axis
          , dashed]
          (-2.5,-1.3)  node[anchor=south east]{$a$} -- (2.5,1.3);
    % Intersection
    \path [name intersections={of=ellipse 1 and oblique axis}] ;
    \fill [color=red] (intersection-1) circle (0.6mm)
          node[anchor=north west]{$A$};
    \draw [thick, ->, >=stealth] (0,0) -- (intersection-1);
    % Origin
    \fill (0,0) circle (0.6mm);
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$O$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Ellipsoid of inertia.}\label{figure:fig03}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because of the `\tikzfading` and has nothing to do with the `background rectangle`. I guess you could get the same issue with a simple `\fbox`. You can see that in the following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadows}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
    \fill (0,0) circle (5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
    \tikzfading[name=test]
    \fill (0,0) circle (5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even better (showing that `backgrounds` is not culprit here) like:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) circle (5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzfading[name=test]
    \fill (0,0) circle (5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An easy fix for this would be to put the `\tikzfading` into the preamble or just in front of the picture. I do not know the manual of this library but I guess this is the recommended way of using it.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    ,intersections
    ,backgrounds
    ,shadows
    }
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    % Fading settings
    \tikzfading[%
        ,name = fade out
        ,inner color = transparent!100
        ,outer color = transparent!10
        ]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
        % Axes
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (-0.6,-0.6) node[anchor=north west]{$X$};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1.2,0)     node[anchor=north]{$Y$};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.2)     node[anchor=east]{$Z$};
         % Ellipse
        \filldraw [% 
            ,draw         = black
            ,fill         = cyan
            ,fill opacity = 0.25
            ,path fading  = fade out
            ,fading angle = -30
            ,name path    = ellipse 1
            ,rotate       = -30
            ]
        (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 3.0cm);
        % Oblique axis
        \draw [name path = oblique axis,dashed](-2.5,-1.3)  node[anchor=south east]{$a$} -- (2.5,1.3);
        % Intersection
        \path [name intersections={of=ellipse 1 and oblique axis}];
        \fill [color=red] (intersection-1) circle (0.6mm) node[anchor=north west]{$A$};
        \draw [thick, ->, >=stealth] (0,0) -- (intersection-1);
        % Origin
        \fill (0,0) circle (0.6mm) node[anchor=north west]{$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ellipsoid of inertia.}\label{figure:fig03}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]